# How to import data from Investing.com into spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, importxml, importhtml

I want to import the live individual stock price in the Google Sheets
as highlighted on the image.

Is that possible?

https://in.investing.com/equities/jagson-airlines-bo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=IMPORTXML("https://in.investing.com/equities/jagson-airlines-bo", 
           "//span[@id='last_last']")
```

[image]

```
=IMPORTXML("https://in.investing.com/equities/jagson-airlines-bo", 
           "//span[@class='arial_26 inlineblock pid-987852-last']")
```

[image]

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://in.investing.com/equities/jagson-airlines-bo", 
                  "TABLE", 12), 2, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, also I want to the result to get updated every min

Comment: @tanmoysinha https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Did this stopped working?